# Heat capacity of slightly interacting bodies

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Consider a classical system made up by two bodies, $A$ and $B$, placed in thermal contact. If the interaction hamiltonian is negligible, we could write the total hamiltonian of the system as $H = H_A+H_B$.

On various treatises, it is said that the heat capacity (at constant volume) $C_V$ of one of the bodies, say, $A$, could be written as  $$C_V=\frac{\langle(\Delta E)^2\rangle}{k_BT^2}$$
However I found another expression, using the hamiltonian $H_A$: $$C_V=\frac{\langle (H_A(final) - H_A (initial))^2\rangle}{2k_BT^2}$$
This implies that $$\langle(\Delta E)^2\rangle=\frac{\langle (H_A(final) - H_A (initial))^2\rangle}{2}$$
Where does the $1/2$ factor come from?

Comment: The first relation is an example of a static fluctuation-dissipation theorem. The proof requires the system to be at thermal equilibrium. I do not know your second relation but $H_A(final)$ and $H_A(initial)$ suggest that $H_A(final)-H_A(initial)$ is the energy variation during a transformation. Jarzynski relation? Definitely, the two relation correspond to different thermodynamic processes and cannot be simply compared.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question, for the sake of completeness.

As @Christophe pointed out, the two expression refer to different concepts: the first is the "classic" heat capacity at thermal equilibrium, $C_V^{eq}$, the second instead is a [time-dependent heat capacity](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.54.2674), $C_V(t)$.

The two could be related via $C_V(t)=C_V^{eq}(1-R_{H_A}(t))$, where $R_{H_A}(t)$ is the autocorrelation function of $H_A$.